# Can you replicate a MySQL 5.1 master to 5.0 slaves?

Tags: mysql, replication

Is it possible to replicate from a MySQL 5.1 master to MySQL 5.0 slaves or are the binary logs not compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-compatibility.html

"Replication from newer masters to older slaves may be possible, but is generally not supported. This is due to a number of factors: "

The answer may depend on your precise versions. If your 5.0 version is 5.0.3 or later you may well get away with it. If 5.0.2 or earlier then I doubt it will work.

But I'm no expert on this.

Comment: Thanks, probably not worth the risk. I'll just end up upgrading all the servers.

Comment: I think that is your best option